# Java Problems Running Minecraft

Tags: lubuntu, java, minecraft

So, I'm running a light version of Ubuntu (Lubuntu), I've been thinking to migrate to Linux for a while now and I want to fully migrate from Windows to Linux, but there's a problem. Mostly because we are operating my Minecraft server with Ubuntu but with Putty. I want it to end there and to use the LXTerminal to operate. Testings need to be done and so forth, so I'm trying to turn Minecraft with the following command:

```
java -jar Minecraft.jar
```

It opens the launcher, everything seems normal... until, I launch the game, it crashes and the crash report is:

> Error: Could not find or load main class java.

My JVM Arguments are `java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar Minecraft.jar nogui` and I've got Java 8 installed.

Answer (score 2):

This problem has now been solved, for those of you which are having the same problem as I did use this as your JVM Arguments:

```
-Xmx1G -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M
```